# How to enable compilation on the fly in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application. I run it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. But if I change C# code, I don't see changes after refreshing the website in the browser. How can I compile on the fly?

Comment: *I run it using Ctrl+F5* it will run with IIS Express. Try to turn it off first (check on your taskbar to the lower right) and then re-run it.

Comment: sorry, no changes    :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens automatically when running out of process. More likely than not, you're working on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app, where the default process model has now been changed to in process. When running in this model, you must explicitly rebuild. You can edit your project properties to switch back to out of process if you like.